# How to execute multiple MERGE INTO query on Oracle DB from Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to run **MERGE INTO** query on `OracleDB` in forEach loop on Node.js code. But only the first query executing and all other failings.

Code:

```
assignedDeals.forEach(async deal => {
          let EXPECTED_DATE = null;
          let STATUS = null;
          let COMMENT = null;
      
      let stmt = `MERGE INTO SP_ASSIGNMENT USING dual ON (ID = ${deal.ID}) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE  SET MODIFIED_DATE = current_timestamp `
      if (deal.STATUS) {
        stmt = stmt + `,STATUS = '${deal.STATUS}'`;
        STATUS = `'${deal.STATUS}'`;
      }
      if (deal.COMMENT) {
        stmt = stmt + `,COMMENT = '${deal.COMMENT}'`;
        COMMENT = `'${deal.COMMENT}'`;
      }
      if (deal.EXPECTED_DATE) {
        stmt = stmt + `,EXPECTED_DATE = '${deal.EXPECTED_DATE}'`;
        EXPECTED_DATE = `'${deal.EXPECTED_DATE}'`
      }
      
      stmt = stmt + `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID,STATUS,ASSIGNED_USER_ID,MODIFIED_DATE,ASSIGNED_RID,ASSIGNED_BY,EXPECTED_DATE,STATUS,COMMENT) 
      VALUES (${deal.ID},'${deal.ISASSIGNED}','${deal.USERID}',current_timestamp,${parseInt(deal.RID)},'${deal.ASSIGNED_BY}',${EXPECTED_DATE},${STATUS},${COMMENT})`;

      console.log(stmt);
      await connection.execute(stmt,{},{
        autoCommit: true
      });
    });
```

Is this the right way to execute multiple queries in for loop?

Any idea why it's not executing the next query?

Help me on this I am new to Node.js + Oracle DB.

Comment: Review the [node-oracledb manual](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#bind).  You MUST use bind variables for security, performance, and scalability.

Comment: Instead of looping, see if you can use [`executeMany()`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#executemany).

Comment: Thanks, @ChristopherJones for your comments it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question so it can help other who have similar issue like this.

So after research on my issue and based on comments I can conclude that through bind variables and `executeMany()` method we can achieve our goal.

**Step 1:** *Prepare your bind parameters like below:*

```
    let binds = [];
    assignedDeals.forEach(deal => {
      binds.push({
        ID: deal.ID,
        USER_ID: deal.USERID,
        RID: parseInt(deal.ASSIGNED_ROLE_ID),
        ASSIGNED_BY: deal.ASSIGNED_BY,
        EXPECTED_DATE: deal.EXPECTED_DATE ? new Date(deal.EXPECTED_DATE) : null,
        STATUS: deal.STATUS ? deal.STATUS : null,
        COMMENT: deal.COMMENT ? deal.COMMENT : null,
        SDC_STATUS: deal.SDC_STATUS ? deal.SDC_STATUS : null,
        DELETED_ON: null
      })
    })
```

**Step 2:** *Prepare ExecuteManyOptions:*

**autoCommit** --> for autocommit your statement.

> Boolean autoCommit
> If this property is true, then the transaction in
> the current connection is automatically committed at the end of
> statement execution.
>
> The default value is false.
>
> This property may be overridden in an `execute()/executeMany()` call.

**bindDefs** --> Bind defs is for type and size specification as per your table defination.

> `Object bindDefs`
> The `bindDefs` object defines the bind variable types,
> sizes, and directions. This object is optional in some cases but it is
> more efficient to set it.
>
> It should be an array or an object, depending on the structure of the
> binds parameter.
>
> Each value in the `bindDefs` array or object should be an object
> containing the keys `dir`, `maxSize`, and `type` for one bind variable,
> similar to how `execute()/executeMany()` bind parameters are identified.

**Example:**

```
const options = {
          autoCommit: true,
          bindDefs: {
            ID: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
            USER_ID: { type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_VARCHAR, maxSize: 20 },
            RID: { type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_NUMBER},
            ASSIGNED_BY: { type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_VARCHAR, maxSize: 20 },
            EXPECTED_DATE: { type: oracledb.DATE },
            STATUS: { type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_VARCHAR, maxSize: 100 },
            COMMENT: { type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_VARCHAR, maxSize: 200 },
            SDC_STATUS: { type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_VARCHAR, maxSize: 20 },
            DELETED_ON: { type: oracledb.DATE },
          }
        };
```

**Step 3:** *Prepare your statement:*

```
const sql = `MERGE INTO SP_ASSIGNMENT USING dual ON (DELETED_ON IS NULL AND ID = :ID) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET MODIFIED_DATE = current_timestamp ,STATUS = :STATUS, SDC_STATUS = :SDC_STATUS,COMMENT = :COMMENT,EXPECTED_DATE = :EXPECTED_DATE 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID,USER_ID,MODIFIED_DATE,RID,ASSIGNED_BY,EXPECTED_DATE,STATUS,COMMENT,SDC_STATUS,DELETED_ON) 
VALUES (:ID,:USER_ID,current_timestamp,:RID,:ASSIGNED_BY,:EXPECTED_DATE,:STATUS,:COMMENT,:SDC_STATUS,:DELETED_ON)`;
```

> **Note:** I prepare the above statement as per my requirements but it's
> very in based on update & insert a condition. You can modify as per
> yours.

**Step 4: Final step** *to call `executeMany()` and pass your SQL statement and bind params and bind options.*

```
result = await connection.executeMany(sql, binds, options);
```

So by following the above 4 steps you can achieve an update or insert based on `USING ON` condition in `MERGE INTO statement`.

Hope this will helps others.